# How to refuse incoming connections in Netty?

Tags: java, netty

I have a Netty TCP server, and I want to reject/refuse incoming connection attempts selectively (based on their remote address). I guess I have to use `ServerBootstrap.setParentHandler(ChannelHandler)`, but what do I do in the `ChannelHandler`? What event am I handling? How do I refuse the connection?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As Norman said, there is no way to refuse the connection, but you can close it immediately by adding a Netty's IpFilterHandler to server pipeline as the first handler. It will also stop propagating the upstream channel state events for filtered connection too.

```
@ChannelHandler.Sharable
public class MyFilterHandler extends IpFilteringHandlerImpl {
  private final Set<InetSocketAddress> deniedRemoteAddress;

  public MyFilterHandler(Set<InetSocketAddress> deniedRemoteAddress) {
    this.deniedRemoteAddress = deniedRemoteAddress;
  }

  @Override
  protected boolean accept(ChannelHandlerContext ctx, ChannelEvent e, InetSocketAddress inetSocketAddress) throws Exception {
    return !deniedRemoteAddress.contains(inetSocketAddress);
  }
}
```

if you have list of patterns of IP address to  block, you can use IpFilterRuleHandler,

```
//Example: allow only localhost:
new IPFilterRuleHandler().addAll(new IpFilterRuleList("+n:localhost, -n:*"))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have several network interfaces and you want to accept connections from one interface only you just need to set the local address in `ServerBootstrap`. This may be enough if your server is running in a machine that's connected to several networks and you want to serve only one of them. In this case any connection attempts from the other networks would be refused by the OS.

Once you have a connection in the application layer it's too late to refuse it. The best you can do is close it immediately.

This is enough if for example you want the server available only on localhost and invisible to the outside world: the loopback network 127.0.0.0/8 is served by a separate interface.

Comment: Right. But is there no way to refuse the connection in Netty? (Again, I'm sure this has to do with `ServerBootstrap.setParentHandler()`)

Comment: Edited to note that if you have several network interfaces you can bind just one and have the OS refuse connections on the others.

Answer (score 0):

After having looked at `org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioServerSocketPipelineSink` in the Netty sources, I am fairly certain that Netty accepts all incoming connections, and there is no way to refuse them (but, of course, they can be closed after being accepted).

Comment: As far as I know there is no way to refuse an incoming connection from a port selectively from socket API level.  Perhaps you need to configure iptables or something similar.