# Camel Netty4 and multiple TCP connections per client

Tags: sockets, tcp, apache-camel, netty

I'm new to Camel and I've been using the [Netty4](http://camel.apache.org/netty4.html) component to manage TCP connections. I'm able to successfully accept a single TCP connection and process/route to ActiveMQ with a **from** URI similar to this: ***"netty4:tcp://localhost:2007?serverPipelineFactory=#tspf&keepAlive=true&sync=false"***.

With that basic functionality working, I now need the ability to accept/reject multiple TCP connections from a given client. Using a lookup file where each entry contains a client **IP:port** tuple and the **maximum_number_of_connections** allowed for that client, accept a new connection from the client if the connection would not exceed the maximum allowed connections for that client.  If the new connection request would cause the maximum allowed TCP connections for that client to be exceeded, then deny/reject the request and also disconnect all currently established TCP connections for that client.  This is done as a means to force the client to re-sync and request all TCP connections anew.

I see the following somewhat similar topics, but none with the requirement to also drop all currently established connections if a subsequent request would exceed the maximum configured value:

1. [Netty4: How can i limit the number of connections?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20634956/netty4-how-can-i-limit-the-number-of-connections)
2. [How to refuse incoming connections in Netty?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9026090/how-to-refuse-incoming-connections-in-netty)

Comment: Why? If the client creates too many connections just reject the ones over the quota. Closing all the other connections and forcing him to reconnect and forcing yourself to re-accept and re-check all those connections is just creating extra work for everybody: yourself, the client, and the network. Seems like a poorly thought out requirement.

Comment: I hear you, but it's currently how things work with this particular set of clients in production, and I must comply!

Comment: Well then you just close the current connections and all others with the same remote `SocketAddress.` Just a data structure problem.

Comment: Thanks EJP.  Any tips on how to approach this idea?  Is it something that can be added to the ChannelPipeline? I'm looking into [this](http://netty.io/3.5/api/org/jboss/netty/handler/ipfilter/IpFilteringHandler.html) without much luck, thus far.  I'm using Apache Camel and Netty4 component. I also see this [topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16368650/limit-number-of-connections-per-ip-on-netty) that talks about modifying the source code for OneIpFilterHandler.  I'm using a consumer-linked channel pipeline factory for TCP receive whereby I'm converting the TCP payload to JSON.